# Read html inside XML feed using XmlPullParser

Tags: android, html, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

How to read html contents inside XML,using XlPullParser in Android project.
ex:What's inside  in this
[Facebook feed](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=835130189832679).
Note:it may contains images, albums, videos...
Update:i need to parse the content of ![CDATA[

Answer (score 0):

On [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html), there is a nice example on how to use the XmlPullParser.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException.html;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
public class SimpleXmlPullApp {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader ("<foo>Hello World!</foo>"));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("End document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you man, i successfully parsed my feed but i need to read the html inside, in a way that the web view can understand (html).